# how to obtain zurb 6 range slider's current value

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

Not sure I could find documentation for how to get the current value of the slider.
This doesn't work although the jquery selector returns the right object:

```
$('.slider').attr('data-slider')
```

Surely it must be easy....

Comment: Would you check the answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

The input element in the div container contains the slider value. See my example below pulled straight from the Zurb simple example with an ID added to the hidden input and referred to by the button onclick event.

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-end="200">
    <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
    <input type="hidden" id="slide1value">
</div>
<div class="column row no-print">
    <input onclick="alert($('#slide1value').val());" value="CLick here for slider1 value.">
</div>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#basics

Comment: Thanks I found that out by now as a workaround. Although I was looking for a way where there's no need to make the html more messy by introducing a hidden element).

Comment: Sorry, adding the input element is the standard for zurb. It does answer your question correctly, no?